# memory mangement of list of pointers containning vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, linked-list

I am testing this code to see how program memory is managed, thanks to windows resource monitor.

```
class A {
public:
        string name_;
        vector<double> H;
        vector<float> G;
        vector<string> I;
        int abc;
};
list<A *> test (90000);

void allocate_class() {
    for (list<A *>::iterator it= test.begin(); it != test.end();it++) {
         A *ptr=*it;
         ptr = new A;
    }
}

void init_fct() {
    for (list<A *>::iterator it= test.begin(); it != test.end();it++) {
        A *ptr=*it;
         /* 
        all above doesnt work program crash

        (*ptr).name_ = "hello test";
        ptr->name_ = "hello test";
        ptr->abc = 57; 
        */

    }
}

void erase_class() {
     list<A *>::iterator it= test.begin();
     while( it != test.end() )
         it = test.erase(it);
 }

void delete_ptr() {
    for (list<A *>::iterator it= test.begin(); it != test.end();it++) {
        A *ptr=*it;
        delete ptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
int t;

cout << "before allocation" << endl;
cin >> t;

allocate_class();

cout << "after allocation" << endl;
cin >> t;

init_fct();

cout << "after init" << endl;
cin >> t;

erase_class();

cout << "after erase" << endl;
cout << test.size();
cin >> t;

delete_ptr();
cout << "after delete" << endl;
cout << test.size();
cin >> t;
```

### Questions:

1. Is the operator delete section really needed in this case ? (not sure if it's really free space)
2. What am I doing wrong/missing in `init_fct()` ?

Note: (attributes are public on purpose, `cin` is to pause the program and check memory state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     A *ptr=*it;
     ptr = new A;
```

This makes a *copy* of the (uninitialised) pointer stored in your list, and then assigns to that copy (and not the pointer on the list) the pointer to your newly allocated instance of `A`. Then the copy goes out of scope, and you have a memory leak.

And of course, since the pointers in the list haven't changed, using them later leads to undefined behaviour.

To fix that, change the pointers in the list:

```
     *it = new A;
```

---

Concerning your `erase_class` function: It's now correct, in the sense that it clears the list. But as you call it before deleting the pointers in the list, you still have a memory leak:

You first remove all pointers from your list, then try to delete the allocated memory. But since you don't have any pointers left in your list, iterating over it will just do nothing.

Looking at your goal, examining memory usage, it's probably something along this what you want:

```
list<A*> l;
cin >> dummy;
// The list will allocate space to hold the pointers:
l.resize (90000);
cin >> dummy;
// Allocate instances for each pointer in the list
for (auto & ptr : l) {
  ptr = new A{};
}
cin >> dummy;
// Free the allocated instances
for (auto & ptr : l) {
  delete ptr;
}
cin >> dummy;
// Erase all elements from the list.
// Note that this is not necessary, when
// the list goes out of scope at the end
// of main this is done by the list destructor.
// Moreover, there's a function to erase
// all elements from the list:
//  l.clear();
auto it = l.begin();
while (it != l.end()) {
  it = l.erase(it);
}
cin >> dummy;
```

---

Note that using smart pointers (or in this case no pointers at all) as elements of your list frees you from the burden to manually delete the allocated memory.

Comment: ok thanks now seems the function init_fct() stuck in an infinite loop and keep displaying "hello test"

Comment: Please show the modified code. Printing 90000 lines of hello world won't happen instantly, though.

Comment: oh sorry i forget i had set 90000 lines it's ok normal it takes too long i thought it was an ifnfinite loop

Comment: That erase function is also not correct, will edit my answer later.

Comment: i found the mistake, the idea is i sholdnt increment the iterator if a use the methode .erase() since i want to erase all items no incrementation i edit my question and correct erase_class() function thanks for letting me know

Comment: there is no methode called reserve() for list

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking about resize, changed it :)